# Limits of the function given by the following graph

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, continuity

[image: Graph]

> Let $$
> f(x)=\left\{ 
> \begin{array}{c}
> 3-x, \ \ \ x<2 \\ 
> (x/2) +1, \ \ \ x>2 \\ 
> \end{array}
> \right. 
> $$
>
> (a) Find $\lim_{x\to 4^+}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to 4^-} f(x)$
>
> (b) Does  $\lim_{x\to 4}f(x)$ exist? If so, what is it?

Here's what I got:

(a) $\lim_{x\to 4^+}f(x)=3$ and $\lim_{x\to 4^-}f(x)=3$

(b) Yes, 3

Is that right?

---

The circles in the graph mean that the point there is "open", as in open\closed intervals.

Comment: The limit at $4^+$ ? There is no discontinuity at $x = 4$ so this is trivial. Are you sure you don't mean $2^+$ ?

Comment: Sorry it was (x/2) +1

Comment: @AniketBinwade There is still no discontinuity at $x=4$

Comment: A graph doesn't have a limit. However the function whose graph is as shown might.

Comment: Doesn't have to be a discontinuity at 4.  This could be a test you concept question.  As f(x) is continuous at 4 the lim_x->4 f(x) = f(4).  No problem.  Trivial in fact.  So yes, you are right.  Although it'd be nice if you gave reasons.  Notice the answer is *very* different for x -> 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now, when the limit tends to $4$ (since $4>2$),you take the equation $f(x)=\frac{x}{2}+1$, then: 
$$\lim_{x\to4^+}\frac{x}{2}+1=\lim_{x\to4^-}\frac{x}{2}+1=3$$
like the lateral limits are equal, the limit in that point exist.

Comment: Sorry it was $(x/2) +1$ Forgot to add the +1

Comment: then your answer is ok

Comment: i edited my answer too. Lol